# JavaScript/jQuery multi-level accordion won't close checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I click on one of the 'main' checkboxes it opens but when I click on the other 'main' checkbox it does not close the previous checkbox. Also if I open one of the 'main' checkboxes then click on a checkbox inside it won't expand that checkbox but instead it closes the 'main' checkbox and then none of the checkboxes open without reloading the page, see example [here](https://codepen.io/tom-han/pen/PoqOdoX).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Settings</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="accordion">
            <div class="accordion-tab">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" class="accordion-input" name="accordion">
                <label class="accordion-label" for="checkbox-1"></label>
                <div class="accordion-content">
                    <div class="accordion-info">
                        <div class="platform-image"></div>
                        <span class="platform-name">Lorem ipsum</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="total-games">
                        <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="accordion-tab-content">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="accordion-tab">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2" class="accordion-input" name="sub-accordion">
                            <label class="accordion-label" for="checkbox-2"></label>
                            <div class="accordion-content">
                                <div class="accordion-info">
                                    <div class="game-image"></div>
                                    <span class="game-name">Lorem ipsum</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="total-games">
                                    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="accordion-tab-content">
                                <div class="wrapper">
                                    <div>
                                        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin id congue dolor. Vivamus eleifend vitae nunc sed tincidunt.</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="accordion-tab">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-3" class="accordion-input" name="accordion">
                <label class="accordion-label" for="checkbox-3"></label>
                <div class="accordion-content">
                    <div class="accordion-info">
                        <div class="platform-image"></div>
                        <span class="platform-name">Lorem ipsum</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="total-games">
                        <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="accordion-tab-content">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="accordion-tab">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-4" class="accordion-input" name="sub-accordion">
                            <label class="accordion-label" for="checkbox-4"></label>
                            <div class="accordion-content">
                                <div class="accordion-info">
                                    <div class="game-image"></div>
                                    <span class="game-name">Lorem ipsum</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="total-games">
                                    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="accordion-tab-content">
                                <div class="wrapper">
                                    <div>
                                        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin id congue dolor. Vivamus eleifend vitae nunc sed tincidunt.</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      <div class="accordion-tab">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-5" class="accordion-input" name="sub-accordion">
                            <label class="accordion-label" for="checkbox-5"></label>
                            <div class="accordion-content">
                                <div class="accordion-info">
                                    <div class="game-image"></div>
                                    <span class="game-name">Lorem ipsum</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="total-games">
                                    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="accordion-tab-content">
                                <div class="wrapper">
                                    <div>
                                        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin id congue dolor. Vivamus eleifend vitae nunc sed tincidunt.</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
body {
    background-color: #6fcae7;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#accordion {
    margin: 50px 0 0;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.accordion-tab {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto 10px; /* 10px adds to bottom */
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #ececec;
}

.accordion-tab:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
}

.accordion-input {
    display: none;
}

.accordion-input:checked ~ .accordion-content + .accordion-tab-content {
    max-height: 3000px;
}

.accordion-input:checked ~ .accordion-content:after {
    transform: rotate(0);
}

.accordion-label {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 80px;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion-content {
    position: relative;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 0 87px 0 30px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.accordion-content:before, .accordion-content:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.accordion-content:before {
    height: 100%;
}

.accordion-label:hover ~ .accordion-content:after {
  background-image: url("accordion-arrow-hover.svg");
}

.accordion-content:after {
    width: 24px;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("accordion-arrow.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.accordion-content + .accordion-tab-content {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height .3s;
}

.accordion-content > div, .total-games > div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.accordion-info {
    width: 95%;
}

.accordion-tab-content {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    color: #363636;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 50px;
}

.platform-image {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 44px;
    width: 44px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.platform-name {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #242a32;
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #242a32;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.total-games {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #5d5d5d;
}

.game-image {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 44px;
    width: 44px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.game-name {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #242a32;
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #242a32;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.game-metadata {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #5d5d5d;
}
```

```
$(".accordion-content").click(function(e) {
  $this
    .parent()
    .parent()
    .find(".accordion-content")
    .removeClass("show");
  $this
    .parent()
    .parent()
    .find(".accordion-tab-content")
    .slideUp(350);
  $this.next().toggleClass("show");
});

$("[name='accordion']").on("click", function() {
  $("[name='accordion']")
    .not($(this))
    .prop("checked", false);
  $(this).prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
  if (!$(this).prop("checked"))
    $(this)
      .siblings(".accordion-tab-content")
      .find("input")
      .prop("checked", false);
});

$("[name='sub-accordion']").on("click", function() {
  $("[name='sub-accordion']")
    .not($(this))
    .prop("checked", false);
  $(this).prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
  if (!$(this).prop("checked"))
    $(this)
      .siblings(".accordion-tab-content")
      .find("input")
      .prop("checked", false);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `type` attribute `checkbox` to `radio`.

```js
$('.accordion-tab-content').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
  
    var $this = $(this);
  
    if ($this.next().hasClass('show')) {
        $this.next().removeClass('show');
        $this.next().slideUp(350);
    } else {
        $this.parent().parent().find('.accordion-tab').removeClass('show');
        $this.parent().parent().find('.accordion-tab-content').slideUp(350);
        $this.next().toggleClass('show');
        $this.next().slideToggle(350);
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #6fcae7;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#accordion {
    margin: 50px 0 0;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.accordion-tab {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto 10px; /* 10px adds to bottom */
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #ececec;
}

.accordion-tab:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
}

.accordion-input {
    display: none;
}

.accordion-input:checked ~ .accordion-content + .accordion-tab-content {
    max-height: 3000px;
}

.accordion-input:checked ~ .accordion-content:after {
    transform: rotate(0);
}

.accordion-label {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 80px;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion-content {
    position: relative;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 0 87px 0 30px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.accordion-content:before, .accordion-content:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.accordion-content:before {
    height: 100%;
}

.accordion-label:hover ~ .accordion-content:after {
  background-image: url("accordion-arrow-hover.svg");
}

.accordion-content:after {
    width: 24px;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("accordion-arrow.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.accordion-content + .accordion-tab-content {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height .3s;
}

.accordion-content > div, .total-games > div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.accordion-info {
    width: 95%;
}

.accordion-tab-content {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    color: #363636;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 50px;
}

.platform-image {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 44px;
    width: 44px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.platform-name {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #242a32;
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #242a32;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.total-games {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #5d5d5d;
}

.game-image {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 44px;
    width: 44px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.game-name {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #242a32;
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #242a32;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.game-metadata {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #5d5d5d;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Settings</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="accordion">
            <div class="accordion-tab">
                <input type="radio" id="checkbox-1" class="accordion-input" name="accordion">
                <label class="accordion-label" for="checkbox-1"></label>
                <div class="accordion-content">
                    <div class="accordion-info">
                        <div class="platform-image"></div>
                        <span class="platform-name">Lorem ipsum</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="total-games">
                        <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="accordion-tab-content">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="accordion-tab">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2" class="accordion-input" name="sub-accordion-1">
                            <label class="accordion-label" for="checkbox-2"></label>
                            <div class="accordion-content">
                                <div class="accordion-info">
                                    <div class="game-image"></div>
                                    <span class="game-name">Lorem ipsum</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="total-games">
                                    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="accordion-tab-content">
                                <div class="wrapper">
                                    <div>
                                        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin id congue dolor. Vivamus eleifend vitae nunc sed tincidunt.</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="accordion-tab">
                <input type="radio" id="checkbox-3" class="accordion-input" name="accordion">
                <label class="accordion-label" for="checkbox-3"></label>
                <div class="accordion-content">
                    <div class="accordion-info">
                        <div class="platform-image"></div>
                        <span class="platform-name">Lorem ipsum</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="total-games">
                        <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="accordion-tab-content">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="accordion-tab">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-4" class="accordion-input" name="sub-accordion-2">
                            <label class="accordion-label" for="checkbox-4"></label>
                            <div class="accordion-content">
                                <div class="accordion-info">
                                    <div class="game-image"></div>
                                    <span class="game-name">Lorem ipsum</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="total-games">
                                    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="accordion-tab-content">
                                <div class="wrapper">
                                    <div>
                                        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin id congue dolor. Vivamus eleifend vitae nunc sed tincidunt.</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      <div class="accordion-tab">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-5" class="accordion-input" name="sub-accordion-2">
                            <label class="accordion-label" for="checkbox-5"></label>
                            <div class="accordion-content">
                                <div class="accordion-info">
                                    <div class="game-image"></div>
                                    <span class="game-name">Lorem ipsum</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="total-games">
                                    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="accordion-tab-content">
                                <div class="wrapper">
                                    <div>
                                        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin id congue dolor. Vivamus eleifend vitae nunc sed tincidunt.</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Use jQuery to implement pseudo radio button via checkbox.

```js
$(".accordion-content").click(function(e) {
  $this
    .parent()
    .parent()
    .find(".accordion-content")
    .removeClass("show");
  $this
    .parent()
    .parent()
    .find(".accordion-tab-content")
    .slideUp(350);
  $this.next().toggleClass("show");
});

$("[name='accordion']").on("click", function() {
  $("[name='accordion']")
    .not($(this))
    .prop("checked", false);
  $(this).prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
  if (!$("[name='accordion']").prop("checked"))
    $(".accordion-tab-content")
    .find(" input")
    .prop("checked", false);
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #6fcae7;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#accordion {
  margin: 50px 0 0;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.accordion-tab {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  /* 10px adds to bottom */
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #ececec;
}

.accordion-tab:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
}

.accordion-input {
  display: none;
}

.accordion-input:checked~.accordion-content+.accordion-tab-content {
  max-height: 3000px;
}

.accordion-input:checked~.accordion-content:after {
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.accordion-label {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 80px;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion-content {
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 0 87px 0 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.accordion-content:before,
.accordion-content:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.accordion-content:before {
  height: 100%;
}

.accordion-label:hover~.accordion-content:after {
  background-image: url("accordion-arrow-hover.svg");
}

.accordion-content:after {
  width: 24px;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("accordion-arrow.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.accordion-content+.accordion-tab-content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .3s;
}

.accordion-content>div,
.total-games>div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.accordion-info {
  width: 95%;
}

.accordion-tab-content {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  color: #363636;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 50px;
}

.platform-image {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 44px;
  width: 44px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.platform-name {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #242a32;
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #242a32;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.total-games {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5d5d5d;
}

.game-image {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 44px;
  width: 44px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.game-name {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #242a32;
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #242a32;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.game-metadata {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5d5d5d;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Settings</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="accordion">
    <div class="accordion-tab">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" class="accordion-input" name="accordion">
      <label class="accordion-label" for="checkbox-1"></label>
      <div class="accordion-content">
        <div class="accordion-info">
          <div class="platform-image"></div>
          <span class="platform-name">Lorem ipsum</span>
        </div>
        <div class="total-games">
          <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion-tab-content">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="accordion-tab">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2" class="accordion-input" name="sub-accordion-1">
            <label class="accordion-label" for="checkbox-2"></label>
            <div class="accordion-content">
              <div class="accordion-info">
                <div class="game-image"></div>
                <span class="game-name">Lorem ipsum</span>
              </div>
              <div class="total-games">
                <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-tab-content">
              <div class="wrapper">
                <div>
                  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin id congue dolor. Vivamus eleifend vitae nunc sed tincidunt.</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion-tab">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-3" class="accordion-input" name="accordion">
      <label class="accordion-label" for="checkbox-3"></label>
      <div class="accordion-content">
        <div class="accordion-info">
          <div class="platform-image"></div>
          <span class="platform-name">Lorem ipsum</span>
        </div>
        <div class="total-games">
          <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion-tab-content">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="accordion-tab">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-4" class="accordion-input" name="sub-accordion-2">
            <label class="accordion-label" for="checkbox-4"></label>
            <div class="accordion-content">
              <div class="accordion-info">
                <div class="game-image"></div>
                <span class="game-name">Lorem ipsum</span>
              </div>
              <div class="total-games">
                <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-tab-content">
              <div class="wrapper">
                <div>
                  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin id congue dolor. Vivamus eleifend vitae nunc sed tincidunt.</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="accordion-tab">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-5" class="accordion-input" name="sub-accordion-2">
            <label class="accordion-label" for="checkbox-5"></label>
            <div class="accordion-content">
              <div class="accordion-info">
                <div class="game-image"></div>
                <span class="game-name">Lorem ipsum</span>
              </div>
              <div class="total-games">
                <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-tab-content">
              <div class="wrapper">
                <div>
                  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin id congue dolor. Vivamus eleifend vitae nunc sed tincidunt.</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you for solution but unfortunately I cannot uncheck the radio button.

Comment: @MisterJojo I missed it problem. I added another solution. thank you!

Comment: @TomHam I added another solution. Check it out.

Comment: @MisterJojo You're right. `input` and `+` selector's styling technique is actually not pratical.

Comment: @sanriot awesome works with the 'main/root' checkboxes, but when you click on checkbox inside it closes 'main/root' checkbox and does not open the checkbox you selected and then no checkbox opens.

Comment: The following doesn't stop checkboxes from working when clicking on checkbox inside root checkbox however the chekecbox inside does not close, see updated first post.

`$('.accordion-content').click(function(e) {
    $this.parent().parent().find('.accordion-content').removeClass('show');
    $this.parent().parent().find('.accordion-tab-content').slideUp(350);
    $this.next().toggleClass('show');`

Comment: @Mister Jojo I will have to work on it when I get this working.

Comment: @TomHan it's a metaphor? you know, I don't have an Anglo-Saxon culture like you, so I don't understand the meaning of your answer

Comment: Updated first post. Now when opening checkbox inside a root checkbox it closes the other checkbox inside root however if I click on a root checkbox it closes the opened root checkbox but leaves the checkbox inside closed root checkbox opened.

Comment: @sanriot thanks! I updated my answers with your updates please see, it now closes checkbox inside of root if you click on the root checkbox but if you click on another root checkbox it stays open.

Comment: @sanriot do you have any suggestions on what I can use to swap out `input and + selector's styling technique is actually not pratical`